# Problems with ScheduledTask Timespec in Mathematica 12.0

Tags: scheduledtask

I am having a problem using the timespec specified in the Wolfram documentation for ScheduledTask.  I believe the issue has been extant since v11.

Let's take an example from the documentation:

```
obj = LocalSubmit[ScheduledTask[DateString[], "Hourly"], 
  HandlerFunctions -> <|"ResultReceived" -> Print|>, 
  HandlerFunctionsKeys -> "EvaluationResult"]
```

[image]

Check the list of tasks:
[image]

Remove the task:
[image]

Confirm the task has been removed:

[image]

Now specify the same scheduled task, with a starting date/time. This works ok:

```
obj = LocalSubmit[ScheduledTask[DateString[], {Now, "Hourly"}], 
  HandlerFunctions -> <|"ResultReceived" -> Print|>, 
  HandlerFunctionsKeys -> "EvaluationResult"]
```

[image]

But when we try to specify a start date, it fails:
[image]

```
obj = LocalSubmit[ScheduledTask[DateString[], {Now, "Hourly"}], 
  HandlerFunctions -> <|"ResultReceived" -> Print|>, 
  HandlerFunctionsKeys -> "EvaluationResult"]
```

It looks as if the task has been scheduled:
[image]

But this is highly misleading - there is nothing scheduled:

[image]

Nor does datelist format work:

```
obj = LocalSubmit[
  ScheduledTask[DateString[], {{2019, 12, 23, 9, 35, 0}, "Hourly"}], 
  HandlerFunctions -> <|"ResultReceived" -> Print|>, 
  HandlerFunctionsKeys -> "EvaluationResult"]
```

[image]

I have made numerous other attempts to get ScheduledTask to work as per the documentation, without success.

Is anyone aware of a workaround?